# How to set the local path of gradle in gradle-wrapper properties

Tags: eclipse, gradle

For me the site https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip doesn't work(don't know why)so the project doesn't build. So, I got the downloaded gradle and now I want to set the properties in my gradle-wrapper.properties file. Currently it says,

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Now, I have gradle in my machine (path :C:\Downloads) and I want to change the properties here so that the gradle works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the gradle is downloaded C:\Documents\gradle in your machine, you can set the distribution path as

```
distributionUrl=file\:///C:/Documents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

This should work